# How to change an error to a warning with PHPCS?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpcs

I recently started to use [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) for WordPress development. I'm now trying to make some of my plugins/themes compliant with the WP Coding Standard.

For that, I'd like to change some of the rules temporarily from errors to warnings, so I can focus more on the important stuff.

I tried to make that happen by adding rule modifications to the `phpcs.xml.dist` file.

For instance:

```xml
<rule ref="Squiz.Commenting.FunctionComment.Missing">
    <severity>5</severity>
</rule>
```

The error does not show at all when I use `0`-`4` for the severity, for `5` and higher it does. From my online research, this seems expected, since `5` seems to be the default threshold for errors.
So even though this works for changing the severity, it does not change it to a warning (what I was hoping for).

Is there a way to alter the rule, that it becomes a warning?

*Testing:

I have a file with errors, that I want to keep and errors I'd like to switch to warnings. I also have some code that triggers warnings, to make sure that warnings are displayed in the first place.*

Answer (score 1):

Typing out the question made me think about it in a different way and lead me to use different words to search for a solution. It finally brought me to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30723533/1786528) and this solution:

```xml
<rule ref="Squiz.Commenting.FunctionComment.Missing">
    <type>warning</type>
</rule>
```